# Sorting a ListBuffer by Position

Tags: scala, sorting, position, traits

Unfortunately, `scala.util.parsing.input.Position` does not extend `Ordering[Position]`.

To sort a `ListBuffer` of errors based on their position, I use the following code:

```
semanticErrors.sortBy(_.pos)(new Ordering[Position] {
  def compare(x: Position, y: Position): Int = x.line - y.line 
}).toList
```

I'm sure this can be done more elegantly. But how? For example, I noticed that `Position` implements `<`. Is there a generic wrapper which turns something that supports `<` into an `Ordering`?

---

Interestingly, this seems to be a lot easier when converting to a `List` first:

```
semanticErrors.toList.sort((a, b) => a.pos < b.pos)
```

But this is probably not the most efficient solution. An in-place sort of the `ListBuffer` would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sortWith` as drexin says is easiest as a one-off, but a couple of notes:

1) `sort` is deprecated, so don't use it. The docs tell you to use `sortWith` instead.

2) `Ordering` is a typeclass, so things don't extend it (unlike `Ordered`) . You just need to have one in implicit scope, which would normally be in a companion object. However `Position` doesn't have a companion. So you can add the implicit yourself:

```
implicit val posOrd: Ordering[Position] = Ordering.fromLessThan(_ < _)
```

Then `semanticErrors.sortBy(_.pos)` should work.

Answer (score 8):

You can sort a `ListBuffer` with the `sortWith` method:

```
semanticErrors.sortWith(_.pos < _.pos)
```

Comment: I know, but the OP explicitly asked for `ListBuffer`.

Comment: Note that this is not an in-place sort.  None of the collections sorts are.